# Ubereats: How to get a list of finished orders

Tags: uber-api

I want to get a list of finished orders from [Eats API](https://developer.uber.com/docs/eats/introduction), but it doesn't seem that there's an endpoint for this purpose.

I guess it might be supposed to be done with CSV files provided by [Reporting API](https://developer.uber.com/docs/eats/api/v1/post-eats-report), but is there any direct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here in Ubereats API you have list of states of an order :
https://developer.uber.com/docs/eats/guides/order-states (there is : "finished")

Try to put this state in the scope when you try to do the GET request.
Hope this track will help